# Find function with higher growth rate

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics

I'm trying to find which function has higher growth rate.

$$f(n) = 2^{n^2 + n}$$
$$g(n) = 5^{12 * n + n * log_2n}$$

I've tried L'Hopital's rule several times, but failed.

Maybe we have another approach?

Comment: Try writing $g(n)$ in the same form as $f(n)$ and then do L'Hopital's.

Comment: @aleden sorry, I had a typo. Instead of 4 $g(n)$ should have 5

Comment: Possible hint. $5 = 2^{\log_2(5)}$ may allow you to compare exponents.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you. If I get it right, then I should do ${2^{log_25}}^{12 * n + n * log_2n} = 2^{(12 * n + n * log_2n) * log_25}$ and then just compare $ n^2 + 2 $ and $(12 * n + n * log_2n) * log_25$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, compare $n^2+ 2$ to the other exponent. This should be straightforward since it's easy to compute $f(n)/g(n)$ when both exponent bases are $2$. As a matter of principle and elegance you should avoid L'Hopital when possible. Search on this site for reasons.

Comment: @EthanBolker if we can express base using log, does it mean that if we compare two functions with different base (some integers), the base actually doesn't matter?

Comment: @NoNameQA See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the $5$ to a $2$:
$$
g(n) = 5^{12  n + n  \log_2n} = 2^{(\log_2 5 )(12  n + n  \log_2n)}
$$

Now both $f$ and $g$ are written as powers of $2$

To see which of $2^{a(n)}$ and $2^{b(n)}$ grows faster, you want to look at
$$
\frac{2^{a(n)}}{2^{b(n)}} = 2^{a(n)-b(n)}
$$
when $n$ is large. So look at the difference $a(n)-b(n)$.

(Of course you will reach the same conclusion if you convert ti $5$ to a $2$, essentially because $\log_2(n)$ and $\log_5(n)$ are proportional - a useful fact I often find surprising even though I've known it for years.)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand the following thing: if I will calculate $2^{a(n)-b(n)}-$ I will get $2^{something}$ But I need to find which function has higher growth rate. How it could help me?

Comment: That something is a function of $n$. If it has limit $\infty$ as $n$ grows then $f$ grows faster than $g$. If the limit is $-\infty$ the reverse is true. If the limit is finite they have the same growth rate.